# Working with Access from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access

```
'Create the recordset
Set dbRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
dbRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseServer
dbRecordset.Open Source:="Table1", _
ActiveConnection:=dbConnection, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, _
LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable

'dbRecordset.AddNew


dbRecordset(Cells(2, 3).Value) = Cells(1, 1).Value

dbRecordset.Update

'Close the connections.
dbRecordset.Close
dbConnection.Close
```

I'm trying to make an application with a feature that stores data into access from excel  (Never have used access). I was able to connect them, and send values to the database. I believe the problem I am having is with the above piece of code. The dbRecordset(Cells(2, 3) to me it seems like the value should go to row/record 2 field 3, but it writes to (2,3). Trying to write to (1,1) gives me an error. I think I could write a for each loop that will move the data I need, but I don't understand where it will go.

Something that could bypass all of this is if I could trigger a DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method that access has built in from excel. I do not know the syntax to write something like (sql, shell?). If you could point me in the right direction of where do write a doCmd command that would be appreciated as it would be much faster than looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweak this a bit.  You can run it from Excel:

```
Sub LoadSheet()
Dim accappl As Access.Application
Dim strpathdb As String
Dim strpathxls As String
Dim myrange As String, myrow1 As String, myrow2 As String

myrow1 = Range("a1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row
myrow2 = Range("a1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlDown).Row

myrange = ActiveSheet.Name & "!A" & myrow1 & ":H" & myrow2

'path to the database
strpathdb = "X:\cre\dep\STRAT_PLAN\StratPlan.mdb"
'path to the upload file
strpathxls = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
Set accappl = New Access.Application

accappl.OpenCurrentDatabase strpathdb

accappl.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, _
            tablename:="Tbl_Growth_Metric", _
            Filename:=strpathxls, Hasfieldnames:=True, _
            Range:=myrange, SpreadsheetType:=5
            'The Spreadsheet type = 5 specifies an Excel 5.0/7.0 file
            'format

MsgBox "All records are loaded"

accappl.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Tweaking it right now, thanks a ton. I think this is what I am looking for.

Comment: If it works, please come back and give me a checkmark for having the right answer.  :o)